# Derivation of the Gibbsian distribution: Ensembles

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I am trying to understand the derivation of the Gibbsian distribution for my statistical mechanics class.

I have spent many hours wrapping my head around the following two paragraphs. But I cannot understand the picture of what they're doing. **Is it that we are dividing system 1 into two subsystems, $E_i^1$ and $E_k^2$>? Or that they are dividing system 1 into two subsystems, system 0 and system 2? If so, what is the point of that?**

Thank you for any help!

[image]

Comment: What is the book this page is coming from?

Comment: Statistical Physics by Gregory Wannier

Answer (score 1):

I have rarely found a notation more confusing than this one.

Who wrote that page considers the **system of interest as system $1$**. The set of all the systems, including system $1$ and many more systems like system 1, is called **system $0$**. **System $2$ is system $0$ without system $1$** (the complement of system $1$ with respect to system $0$).

In practice, system $0$ is the union of system $1$ and system $2$.

What is the point of that? It is the starting point for deriving the probability of finding system $1$ in a state of energy $E^1_i$ from the knowledge that system $0$ is an isolated system with fixed energy.

Comment: Thank you! Just to make sure I understand, it is the starting point of getting $p^1(E_i^1)$ given that system 0 is an isolated system with fixed energy. Why do we care about system 0 being an isolated system with fixed energy?

Comment: @hu234 I think the pages of the book following the one you showed should explain why. I can only guess that the author could derive the probability density of the canonical ensemble from a maximum entropy request with the constraint that the total energy of system $0$ is kept constant.